What is the history of live animal securitization? Has there ever been an market where shares of animal ownership were sold like stocks?
What is the history of live animal securitization? Has there ever been an exchange where shares of animal ownership were sold like stocks?

http://www.cmegroup.com/rulebook/CME/II/100/101/101.pdf live cattle futures for example

Thank you. Since I am writing a proposal on this matter I can use as many references as I can find, so I'll be grateful if you have other examples you could share with me

Also I am specifically looking for live animal's stock market where their shares are sold and not speculation over their price. Do you know of any examples? Is there any precedence?

These futures are deliverable, meaning you get animals. If it's not deliverable in the future it's just a market. It makes no sense to securities animals when you want to trade them today. What exactly are you writing a proposal for without knowing these markets?

The proposal is about race animals which are not traded as frequent as live stock and have less buyers. The goal is to open a market for better investment. It's not about using their meat but the investment for their growth and wins in contests.

I don't anything about this but check out the athlete stocks that exist. I suspect race horses and the like are traded infrequently because it's a prestigious possession. So it likely works better to not actually sell the animal but use a workaround like athlete stocks do.

Thank you so much for your help
